# List of symbols with corresponding names

Tags: data-request, internet

I am searching for wording for symbols icons and what they are. For example, if you have a symbol such as flag, or types of cars. I want to look it up online and search for the name of that symbol.  I know that there are tons of them online but what I would like to have a general thousands of symbols or icons and if you don't know what they are you can pull it up and look for it.

I know it is hard for me to describe. I am a GIS Specialist and sometimes I get a hardcopy maps and I have some odd symbols and I couldn't find it on my software to match it. So, when I google and I couldn't find it either...

Comment: You might find the [Noun Project](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=pencil) helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can also look at the [Unicode character charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/), specially at the block [Miscellaneous Symbols](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2600.pdf) and at the two blocks named [Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F300.pdf) and [Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F900.pdf). The Emoji area can also be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

NPS Map Symbols offers this information:
[image: NPS Map Symbols PDF Screenshot Showing What Is Available]

[Repository has Images](https://github.com/nationalparkservice/symbol-library/tree/gh-pages/src/standalone)

[PDF with Images/Labels](https://www.nps.gov/hfc/carto/SYMBOLS/map_symbols.pdf)

[Wikipedia also has Images/Labels](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:USNPS_map_symbols)

Comment: This is good but I am asking overall all over hundreds of thousands of symbols out there with their names on it...

Comment: you should edit your question to say that

Comment: I make the edits and see if it is further clear or clarification ? Let me know .

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am looking for and found this..

https://www.iconfinder.com/

Thanks !

Comment: that totally sounds different from what i understood your question as. apologies. if you like iconfinder you should check out the noun project: https://thenounproject.com/